# Error on websocket connection when importing a GCP Kubernetes cluster into Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, rancher

I'm having a problem when trying to importing a GKE cluster in Rancher.
After running kubectl use-context & create clusterrolebinding
 Looking at logs at rancher agent, it is having these errors.

```
time="2020-05-30T13:16:42Z" level=error msg="Remotedialer proxy error" error="websocket: bad 
handshake" time="2020-05-30T13:16:52Z" level=info msg="Connecting to wss://rancher.mydomain.com/v3/connect with token 83838383"
time="2020-05-30T13:16:52Z" level=info msg="Connecting to proxy"
url="wss://rancher.mydomain.com/v3/connect"
time="2020-05-30T13:16:52Z" level=error msg="Failed to connect to proxy. Response status: 200 - 200 OK. Response body: node.management.cattle.io \"c-czjxh/m-348cfc5e3bed\" not found" error="websocket: bad handshake"
```

Comment: have the same issue, found the ingress' response in the logs on Rancher side:
`"GET /v3/connect HTTP/1.1" 200 60 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 3558 0.002 [cattle-system-rancher-80] [] 10.42.0.4:80 60 0.000 200 4b2dd02bb332ca322a0d9e8bb3cb2e86`

Comment: Where is your Rancher deployment running? Is it on another network?

Answer (score 0):

This look that is related to: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/24876
I know is an old question but may you still need to check it :)